# JDBCTemplate/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate failed to insert FileItem/Blob

Tags: java, blob, jdbctemplate, named-parameters, column-types

I have a normal `PreparedStatement` that insert `FileItem fileItem` to BLOB column:

```
ps.setBinaryStream(1, fileItem.getInputStream(), (int) fileItem.getSize());
```

The problem I can enter  `FileItem` to `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`:

I tried with `Types.BLOB`:

```
MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
paramSource.addValue("blob",  fileItem.getInputStream(), Types.BLOB);
jdbcTemplate.update(INSERT_FILE, paramSource);
```

But got exception

```
SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10503)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9974)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObject(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10581)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObject(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:249)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setObject(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:469)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:241)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:156)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.setValues(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.createPreparedStatement(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:244)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
```

Same error with `jdbcTemplate` with parameter `BLOB file`:

```
jdbcTemplate.update(INSERT_FILE, file);
```

Failed similarly with different parameters as `File` and `InputStream`

I'm trying to save a (binary) image file

Comment: Did you tried different data type? (let's say, String)

Comment: @lolo I'm not sure String will be enough to store it

Comment: Yes i understand... just want to indicate the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's work only when I change parameter type to `byte[]`:

```
 byte[] blob
```

And use it in insert:

```
jdbcTemplate.update(INSERT_FILE, blob);
```